# Archivos subidos a hosting en Firebase

Tags: firebase, web, hosting, cpanel

Acabo de subir con éxito una pagina web (HTML y CSS unicamente) al Hosting de Firebase. La pagina se visualiza correctamente, pero me gustaría saber si existe algun tipo de CPanel o algo por el estilo que me permita saber cuantos archivos tengo subidos, o si puedo eliminar o editar alguno de ellos, o consultar la fecha de subida de algún archivo concreto...
Y aprovecho la pregunta para consultaros: ¿Para subir archivos a Firebase solo puede hacerse mediante el CLI, es decir, la consola de Firebase? ¿No existe una interfaz mas amigable para tener mayor control de los archivos subidos?
¿Me recomendáis algún hosting gratuito con una interfaz gráfica amigable para subir los archivos y redireccionar la pagina a un dominio adquirido?
Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.
Un saludo!!

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de Firebase, no contas con un cPanel como contarias con otros servicios de hosting, lo que deberias hacer es contratar un servicio de hosting tercero y enlazarlo con Firebase para poder hacer la redirección, en mi caso en una app que estamos usando firebase hosting usamos Hostinger como hosting aparte y luego lo enlazamos a Firebase hosting, de esta forma mantenemos por separado ambas partes